# Bar Plot does Not display properly in browser but show up properly in Jupyter Notebook but

Tags: python, plotly

I made a bar plot that shows up perfectly in jupyter notebook, but it doesn’t work in browser (ran it with VSCode). Can anyone share some insights? The packages are updated.[image]

[image]

The code in VScode is listed as following:

```
bar_fig=go.Figure()

Category=list(df_agg_melt.Category.unique())

bar_fig=px.bar(df_agg_melt, x="Category", y="Percentage", color="Response", facet_col="Course", barmode="group",
                category_orders={
                    "Category": Category,
                    "Response": ['Have', 'Could Include'],
                    "Course":['PSYCH100', 'PSYCH100v2']
                })
bar_fig.update_layout(width=1800, height=800)

# Show the chart
bar_fig.show()
```

Comment: Are there reproducible data and codes? Not with images. Also, your environment information would be even better, as it may be affected by the execution environment.